# ProgressDialog does not dismiss properly in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am writing my first Android application and am having some trouble with dismissing the ProgressDialog in onPostExecute.  I've read through numerous similar questions here on SO,but none of those solutions seemed to fix my particular issue.

The dialog shows up and DOES dismiss, but it isn't doing it the way I want it to. The animation freezes when Filter.apply() is started and does not dismiss until after Filter.apply has completed.  Filter.apply() is another time intensive process that is called from various places.  This method will have its own ProgressDialog.

What have I done incorrectly?

**Here is my AsyncTask**

```
public class JSONFetchFMTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

private Activity activity;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

public JSONFetchFMTask() {}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    Context context = FM.getAppContext();
    Activity activity = ((FM)context.getApplicationContext()).getCurrentActivity();
    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "", "Downloading Data", true);
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   // Process intensive code was here
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    if (dialog != null && dialog.isShowing()) {
      dialog.dismiss();
   }
    Filter.apply();
}
}
```

**And here is my FM class:**

```
public class FM extends Application {

private static Context context;
private Activity currentActivity;


public void onCreate(){
    super.onCreate();
    FM.context = getApplicationContext();
}

public static Context getAppContext() {
    return FM.context;
}

public Activity getCurrentActivity(){
    return this.currentActivity;
}

public void setCurrentActivity(Activity currentActivity) {
    this.currentActivity = currentActivity;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Filter.apply()` is time intensive, you shouldn't run it on the main thread. That's probably why the animation freezes up. You can confirm this if you see a log message that says something like:

"Skipped X frames. Application may be doing too much work on the main thread."

Offload the time intensive aspects of `Filter.apply()` onto another thread. If you want, you can just use another `AsycnTask` to do this.

Comment: This solved the issue.  Filter was badly written with a lot of  code in runOnUiThread() that should not have been there.  I've refactored this and everything is much better.  I'm still having some issues, but that will be a separate question if I cannot figure it out on my own.

Comment: Glad you got everything figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The onPostExecute() method is a hook to the UI thread that AsyncTask objects use to show any results that may be needed. If Filter.apply() is a time intensive process, this will definitely freeze the UI thread and Filter.apply() is now running on the UI thread because it was explicitly asked to run here.

Try to delegate the Filter.apply() onto it's own thread to perform CPU intensive tasks.